# MYSQL Get random 2 Cars, all colors (LEFT JOIN)

Tags: mysql, join, sql-limit

I have a table, Cars,

```
CarID | Car
1       Taurus
2       Ranger
3       Charger
```

and CarColors with colors for each car.

```
ColorID | CarID | Color
1         1       White
2         1       Blue
3         2       Black
4         1       Red
5         2       Pink
6         3       Orange
```

I want to get a random two cars, and all colors for those cars. I tried

```
SELECT * FROM Cars C
  LEFT JOIN CarColors CC ON C.CarID = CC.CarID
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 2
```

But this, understandably, returns two rows.

I tried a subquery, something like

```
SELECT * FROM Cars C
  LEFT JOIN CarColors CC ON C.CarID = CC.CarID
WHERE C.CarID IN (SELECT CarID FROM Cars
                   ORDER BY RAND()
                   LIMIT 2)
```

But MYSQL doesn't support LIMIT within subqueries.

When I try to search for this, I get answers for limiting the JOIN's results (like 1 color for each car)

Comment: Do you mean two random cars of each color? Like two white, two blue, etc? I think the answer could use a window function like the answer posted so far, but slightly differently.

Comment: Also please confirm you are using MySQL 8.0, which is required for window function support. You can use `SELECT VERSION();` to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your MySQL version support `ROW_NUMBER` window function, you can try this

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
  SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY RAND()) rn 
  FROM Cars
) C LEFT JOIN CarColors CC ON C.CarID = CC.CarID
WHERE rn <= 2
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b65ab75d7027fe98d842d1fffbd8d2d8)

Another way is you can just use a subquery to get random cars then do `JOIN`

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
  SELECT * 
  FROM Cars
  ORDER BY RAND()
  LIMIT 2
) C LEFT JOIN CarColors CC ON C.CarID = CC.CarID
```